# Checking if values in column are way above average

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with sales data for each period, for instance:

```
PERIOD         STORE 1
W 2016 16   49,45
W 2016 17   51,02
W 2016 18   51,22
```

Each column represents a store, and I have to manually check over 200 columns for anomalies.

I wrote a code to check the average for each column and then highlight values that are way above/below average, but that did not work so well...

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Dim c As Range, fc As ColorScale

For Each c In Range("A1:CD1").Cells

    Set fc = c.EntireColumn.FormatConditions.AddColorScale( _
                                               ColorScaleType:=3)
    fc.SetFirstPriority
    fc.ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With fc.ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
    fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    fc.ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With fc.ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

Next c
End Sub
```

I'd like to have something that would simply calculate the average for each column, and then highlight in red the values that are, let's say, 15% higher/lower than the highest/lowest value for each column because that'd be probably an error with my DB.

Anyone have any insight on how to do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you need to do this in code?  You could use a statistical formula (say `AVERAGE`) at the top/bottom of the column and then some simple conditional formatting.

Comment: You can create two rules [AboveBeverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.addaboveaverage) with `AboveBelow = xlAboveStdDev` and `AboveBelow = xlBelowStdDev` for example, or create your own formula.

Comment: @Gareth I'd rather have a code since I have many worksheets and creating a macro for doing it on all my reports would be easier. Basically the code above works based on averages, but the effect is kind of messy as I get loads of coloured cells, I'd like to filter that...

Comment: @VincentG Thanks mate! I'll definitely try it :)